How to groupby(col1) and sum(col2), (col3), (col 4)
I want to make a function that creates a data table of the sum of each indicator for each site.
I need to group by the site, as there are 100 Devons, 70 Cornwalls and so on, so that Site is the dependent variable, and Devon reads to have A = 6,  B = 4, C = 2, D = 1.
I have another two column data table which reads site occurence (e.g Devon 2) and will find the average indicators per site later.


| Site     |     A    |     B    |    C     |    D     |
| -------- | -------- | ---------| -------- | -------- |      
| Cornwall |     0    |     1    |    0     |    3     |
| Devon    |     1    |     4    |    1     |    0     |
| Devon    |     5    |     0    |    1     |    1     |

I have tried a few methods, but only get errors. I tried asking AI for the forst time but got this. Still errors.
def CHEGD_funct(df, group_col, sum_cols):
    grouped_sum_df = df.groupby(group_col).sum([sum_cols]).reset_index()
    return grouped_sum_df

    dataframe = pd.read_csv('Grassland_Fungi.csv', low_memory=False)
    sitecolumn = dataframe.iloc[:,6] 
    (Cleaned site column into site list)

    site_col = pd.DataFrame(list(sitelist))
   

    A = dataframe.iloc[:,11]
    B = dataframe.iloc[:,12]
    C = dataframe.iloc[:,13]
    D = dataframe.iloc[:,14]
    ABCD = (A, B, C, D)

functionrun = CHEGD_funct(dataframe, site_col, ABCD)

print(functionrun)


Any recommendations?

don't you just want this? df[['Site', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']].groupby('Site').sum().reset_index() if you're reading from a table with more columns than needed?
